# How to post and populate bill

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've got a relational json called "client" inside Bill's model. This is my code:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const billSchema = new Schema({
  number: Number,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  type: String,
  local: String,
  client: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "clients", required: true },
  detail: [
    {
      quantity: Number,
      product: { code: Number, name: String, price: Number },
      undertotal: Number
    }
  ],
  total: Number
});

mongoose.model("bills", billSchema);
```

this is my post route:

```js
app.post("/api/bills", async (req, res) => {
  const { number, type, local, client, detail, total } = req.body;

  await Client.findById(req.body.client._id).then(client => {
    if (!client) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: "client not found"
      });
    }
  });

  const bill = new Bill({
    number,
    date: new Date(),
    type,
    local,
    client,
    detail,
    total
  });

  try {
    let newBill = await bill.save();

    res.status(201).send(newBill);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === "MongoError") {
      res.status(409).send(err.message);
    }

    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});

//my get route

app.get("/api/bills", function(req, res) {
  Bill.find({}, function(err, bills) {
    Client.populate(bills, { path: "clients" }, function(err, bills) {
      res.status(200).send(bills);
    });
  });
});
```

I want something like this:

```
{
    "number": 302,
    "type": "c",
    "local": "porstmouth",
    "client": {
        "address": {
            "street": "victoria street",
            "number": 1001,
            "floor": "2",
            "flat": 4
        },
        "_id": "5dab929613fb682b48e4ca6b",
        "name": "luke skywalker",
        "mail": "l.skywalker@yahoo.com",
        "cuil": "39193219",
        "phone": 128391,
        "__v": 0
    },
    "detail": [
        {
            "quantity": 500,
            "product": {
                "code": 300,
                "name": "P2",
                "price": 800
            },
            "undertotal": 5000
        }
    ],
    "total": 11000
}
```

But I see this result:

```
{
    "date": "2019-10-20T12:27:17.162Z",
    "_id": "5dac52a577e09b4acc45718d",
    "number": 302,
    "type": "c",
    "local": "porstmouth ",
    "client": "5dab929613fb682b48e4ca6b",
    "detail": [
        {
            "_id": "5dac52a577e09b4acc45718e",
            "quantity": 500,
            "product": {
                "code": 300,
                "name": "P2",
                "price": 800
            },
            "undertotal": 5000
        }
    ],
    "total": 11000,
    "__v": 0
}
```

I don't want to see id client only. I want to see all content from client inside bill. 
I tried to do with populate method, but I haven't results.

So, Which is form to post and populate a nested json relational object in this case?

Comment: can share your Client schema and Bill schema

Comment: bill schema:   const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const billSchema = new Schema({
    
    number: Number,

    date: {type: Date, default: Date.now()},

    type: String,

    local: String,

    client: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'clients',required: true},


    detail: [{
        quantity: Number,

        product: {code: Number,
                  name: String,
                   price: Number
        },
        undertotal: Number
    }
    ],
    total: Number
   
});

mongoose.model('bills', billSchema);

Comment: clientSchema: const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const clientSchema = new Schema({
 
    name: String,
    mail: String,
    cuil: String,
    phone: Number,
    address: {street: String,
    number: Number,
    floor: String,
    flat: Number
    }
    
});

mongoose.model('clients', clientSchema);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While posting only clientId is enough.

So your post route can be like this (you both used await and then, which is incorrect, so I refactored it to use only await)

```
app.post('/api/bills', async (req, res) => {

  const { number, type, local, client, detail, total } = req.body;

  let existingClient = await Client.findById(req.body.client._id)

  if (!existingClient) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      message: "client not found"
    });
  }

  const bill = new Bill({
    number,
    date: new Date(),
    type,
    local,
    client: req.body.client._id
    detail,
    total

  })

  try {
    let newBill = await bill.save();

    res.status(201).send(newBill);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === 'MongoError') {
      res.status(409).send(err.message);
    }

    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

And in the get route to retrieve all the client info you need to populate it like this:

```
app.get('/api/bills', async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const bills = await Bill.find({}).populate("clients");

    res.status(200).send(bills);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
}
)
```

Comment: I still see the client's id inside bill object.

Comment: @FranciscoArias If in mongodb, it is not a problem. Where do you see it?

Comment: If you don't want to see the client id in the response of get route, we can exclude the id

Comment: @FranciscoArias  like this: const bills = await Bill.find({}).populate("clients","address name mail cuil phone -_id");

Comment: I want to see all data from nested relational object client inside bill object. I tried the way you said. But I still see the id in client. Is it normal in mongo db?

Comment: @FranciscoArias  in mongodb Bills collection, it is perfectly normal to see the clientId, that is the only way we can reference the clients collection.

Comment: And I think there is no problem to see the clientId in the response of get route.